# Wildfly 27: No error or warning in case of incorrect security domain specified in web.xml / jboss-web.xml

Tags: authentication, wildfly, undertow, elytron

We use BASIC authentication for a REST API of a WAR deployment (running in Wildfly 27).
Wildfly has been configured accordingly and web.xml / jboss-web.xml refers to the corresponding application-security-domain in the undertow subsystem:

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secured</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>FooRole</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>bar-security-domain</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>bar-security-domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

**standalone-full.xml**

```
<application-security-domain name="bar-security-domain" http-authentication-factory="foobar-auth"/>
```

With that configuration everything works fine (access only with valid user credentials) but what irritated me during the setup:
If a security-domain is specified in web.xml / jboss-web.xml which does not exist as an application-security-domain in the undertow-subsystem (e.g. due to a typo or the security-domain from the elytron-subsystem is mistakenly referenced instead of the application-security-domain from the undertow-subsystem), **the application can be used without any authentication** even thought no default-security-domain is defined in our undertow configuration.

**I would expect:**

- An error that the security domain specified in web.xml / jboss-web.xml was not found or at least a warning that a fallback is being used.
- That the security domain assigned to the application can be traced in the HAL.
  --> I have not been able to find either of these anywhere so far.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to determine which security-domain is assigned to
  an application in Wildfly at runtime?
- Is it a bug or feature that    there is no error/warning in case of
  incorrect security domain in    web.xml / jboss-web.xml (e.g. to be
  able to flexibly    activate/deactivate the security domain via
  configuration in    standalone-full.xml)?
- Is there a configuration option to generate    a error/warning in the event of an incorrect security domain in    web.xml / jboss-web.xml?